# aws-sdk 2.3.0 and Paperclip 5.0.0 bad region

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

Im using the `AWS-SDK 2.3.0` gem with `paperclip 5.0.0` gem.

In my `config/environment/development.rb` file i have

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_region: 'eu-west-1',
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: 'myBucketName',
      access_key_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      secret_access_key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      }
    }
```

My bucket region in set as Ireland when I created my bucket so according to the document provided by AWS i set my s3 region as `eu-west-1`.

Im assuming my details are all correct but, when i upload an image, its gets saved to the bucket but it won't show on my rails app. If i right click on open image in new tab i get this error:

```
<Message>
The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
</Message>
```

Comment: *its gets saved to the bucket but it won't show on my rails app.*  That's an interesting combination of behavior.  When you right-click and open the new tab, what is the hostname of the URL?  The "specified endpoint" error message should mention an endpoint.  What endpoint does it list?  Capturing the HTTP response headers from the failed download may also be useful. (Using `curl -v 'http...'` is a good way to capture this, and edit it into your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work around this is to create a file called:

```
config/initializers/paperclip.rb
```

And add the following:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
```

And in the 3rd line where I have `eu-west-1` replace that depending on the region you are in.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem, too. The issue for me was that I had the wrong region specified in my ENV. Make sure to check the region in S3 by clicking "properties" for your bucket. I was just looking at the region in the URL bar in the Amazon console, which was maybe just the region I'm in.

Also, note that the US Standard region [was renamed](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region) to US East (N. Virginia), with its region string being `us-east-1`.

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a known issue by the team who maintains paperclip.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2151

> aminariana commented on Mar 25 
>   Workaround for now: Configure
>   s3_host_name to s3-[region].amazonaws.com like so:
>
> config.paperclip_defaults = { s3_host_name:
>   "s3-#{ENV['AWS_REGION']}.amazonaws.com", }

Only took googling the exact error message to find this btw.

Comment: @GurmukhSingh you should have mentioned this in your question.   You should also be *very* careful, when testing a proposed solution, confirming that the error with the solution in place is identical in every meaningful way.  "Also fails" doesn't equate to "not correct."